# Swapping array values with destructuring assignment and indexOf()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm trying to swap the two lowest values in a shuffled array containing the numbers 0-14. For those curious, I'm implementing the shuffling algorithm for a 15 puzzle described by [pkpnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9589593/pkpnd) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50869921/12046434).

I wanted to try destructuring assignment, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872317/12046434), but am encountering an unexpected behavior. I realize that I can get my code working (and make it more readable) by just creating a temporary variable, but I'd like to understand what's happening before moving on.

I'm grabbing a subset of my array `[1,2]` and then trying to replace it with `[2,1]`. For some reason, it's only swapping the values when their order in the original array is **opposite** of the order of my subset.

I originally tried this:

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [2, 1, 3, 4];
[arr1[arr1.indexOf(1)], arr1[arr1.indexOf(2)]] = [arr1[arr1.indexOf(2)], arr1[arr1.indexOf(1)]];
[arr2[arr2.indexOf(1)], arr2[arr2.indexOf(2)]] = [arr2[arr2.indexOf(2)], arr2[arr2.indexOf(1)]];
console.log("arr1: " + arr1, "\narr2: " + arr2);
```

And then tried this:

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [2, 1, 3, 4];
[arr1[arr1.indexOf(1)], arr1[arr1.indexOf(2)]] = [2, 1];
[arr2[arr2.indexOf(1)], arr2[arr2.indexOf(2)]] = [2, 1];
console.log("arr1: " + arr1, "\narr2: " + arr2);
```

But both produce identical output:

```
arr1: 1,2,3,4 
arr2: 1,2,3,4
```

I would expect that the position of 1 and 2 would be swapped for both arrays, but they're only swapped in arr2. I suspect this has to do with they way the initial array subset `[1,2]` is created, but I'm not sure.

Can anybody explain why the values aren't always swapped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is simple, because it goes step for step for each item of destructuring assingment. And while the values are changing, the index of the values changes.

#### Case 1 `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

1. Get index of target for the first value `2`

   ```
   [arr1[arr1.indexOf(1)], arr1[arr1.indexOf(2)]] = [2, 1];
   //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                     0
   ```
2. Assign `2` to `arr1[0]`

   ```
   [2, 2, 3, 4]
   ```
3. Get index of target for the second value `1`:

   ```
   [arr1[arr1.indexOf(1)], arr1[arr1.indexOf(2)]] = [2, 1];
   //                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^              0
   ```
4. Assign `1` to `arr1[0]`

   ```
   [1, 2, 3, 4]
   ```

#### Case 2 `[2, 1, 3, 4]`

1. Get index of target for the first value `2`

   ```
   [arr2[arr2.indexOf(1)], arr2[arr2.indexOf(2)]] = [2, 1];
   //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                     1
   ```
2. Assign `2` to `arr1[1]`

   ```
   [2, 2, 3, 4]
   ```
3. Get index of target for the second value `1`:

   ```
   [arr2[arr2.indexOf(1)], arr2[arr2.indexOf(2)]] = [2, 1];
   //                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^              0
   ```
4. Assign `1` to `arr1[0]`

   ```
   [1, 2, 3, 4]
   ```

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thank you! I didn't realize it evaluates each assignment in sequence rather than evaluating each subset first.