# How to find the number of inversions in an array ?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Counting inversions in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array)

This is an [phone interview question](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Phone-Interview-i-Find-the-number-of-inversions-in-an-array-describe-and-code-ii-Find-collinear-points-in-a-given-set-QTN_129352.htm): "Find the number of inversions in an array". I guess they mean O(N*log N) solution. I believe it cannot be better than O(N*log N) since this is the sorting complexity.

The answers to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array) can be summarized as follows:

1. Calculate half the distance the elements should be moved to sort the array : copy the array and sort the copy. For each element of the original array `a[i]` find it's position `j` in the sorted copy (binary search) and sum the halves the distances `abs(i - j)/2`.
2. Modify `merge sort` : modify `merge` to count inversions between two sorted arrays and run regular `merge sort` with that modified `merge`.

   Does it make sense ? Are there other (maybe simpler) solutions ? Isn't it too hard for a phone interview ?

Comment: You can find n log n solution coded in java here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array/6424847#6424847

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is actually an application of divide-and-conquer algorithm, and if you are familiar with it you can come up with the solution quickly.

Take [1 3 8 5 7 2 4 6] as an example, assume we have sorted array as [1 3 5 8] and [2 4 6 7], and now we need to combine the two arrays and get the number of total inversions.

Since we already have number of inversions in each sub-array, we only need to find out the number of inversions caused by array merging. Each time an element is inserted, for example, 2 inserted into [1 # 3 5 8], you can know how many inversions there are between the first array and the element 2 (3 pairs in this example). Then you can add them up to get the number of inversions caused by merging.

Comment: Let we know the number of inversions for 2 halves of the array. How would you combine them to get the number of inversions of the whole array ?

Comment: Thanks for the update. As I understand, the trick is to have both sub-arrays _sorted_. That is, we can count inversions in each of sub-arrays but in order to get the _total number_ of inversions we have to have them sorted.

Comment: @ZelluX -  How can we solve for array with duplicate values as `[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4]` using merge sort ?

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a counting sort-like approach, if the array only contains small numbers for example (like if it's a character array):

```
inversions = 0
let count = array of size array.Length
for i = 0 to array.Length - 1 do
    for j = array[i] + 1 to maxArrayValue do
        inversions = inversions + count[j]

    count[array[i]] = count[array[i]] + 1
```

Basically, keep a count of how many times each element appears. Then at each step `i`, the number of inversions the `i`th element generates is equal to the sum of all the elements bigger than `i` that come before `i`, which you can easily compute using the count you're keeping.

This will be `O(n*eps)` where `eps` is the domain of the elements in your array.

This is definitely simpler in my opinion. As for efficiency, it's only good if `eps` is small obviously. If it is, then it should be faster than other approaches since there's no recursion.