# Counting coprime pairs in array

Tags: algorithm, primes, factors, number-theory

**Size of array<=10^5** and each element in array is **2<=Ai<=10^5**. Is there any way to calculate all the coprime pairs (Ai,Aj) where 1<=**i,j**<=100000 in O(nlogn) ?

Any idea how to use mobious function to solve this?

Comment: What if all the entries are coprime. The number of coprime pairs would be O(n ^ 2)

Comment: Do you want to count how many elements are coprime to a particular A_i or identify all A_j that are coprime to A_i for all i,j? E.g for the set `S = {26, 31, 80, 13}`, are you looking for `M = {1, 3, 2, 2}` (i.e. the number of coprime elements), or `A = {{31}, {26, 80, 13}, {31, 13}, {31, 80}}` (i.e. the actual coprime elements)?

Comment: I am looking for the count. 1+3+2+2=8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting coprimes in a sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807128/counting-coprimes-in-a-sequence)