# Programming interview question (array inversion)

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Counting inversions in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array)

This is a programming question that I had when I was interviewed by a company for a developer job few months ago.

Given an array A of N integers, an *inversion* of the array is defined as any pair of indexes (a,b) such that a<b and A[b]<A[a].

Write a function:

```
int inversion_count(int A[], int n);
```

which computes the number of inversions in A, or returns -1 if such number exceeds 1,000,000,000. For example, in the following array

```
A[0]=-1 A[1]=6 A[2]=3 A[3]=4 A[4]=7 A[5]=4
```

there are four inversions:

```
(1,2)  (1,3)  (1,5)  (4,5)
```

so the function should return 4.

I solved this question in a very common way: using double loop.

```
int i, j;
long count;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for (j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
      if (A[i] > A [j]) count++;
      if (count > 1000000000) break; // exit loop
   }
   if (count > 1000000000) break; // exit loop
}
if (count > 1000000000) return -1;
else return count;
```

So the running time of it is : O (nsquare), and I was told that it was not efficient. I am now thinking of a different way to solve this problem, maybe using an **n log n** algorithm, but I haven't figured it out yet. Any ideas?

Comment: "Given is an array A of N integers, the inversion of the array is a pair of indexes (a,b) such that a ???" Could you please fill in the "???". It looks like you dropped the end of the sentence.

Comment: Could you complete the statement `Given is an array A of N integers, the inversion of the array is a pair of indexes (a,b) such that a`, what is the definition of the inversion?

Comment: @Justin Thanks Justin Ethier for editing the post. I put a less than symbol, and forgot to highlight it as a code format, so the HTML encoder treated it as if it was an html tag. Sorry !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer explains a O(n log n) algorithm: [Counting inversions in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array/338252#338252).

The trick is to first sort (O(n log n)), and then use binary search to find elements (also O(n log n)) resulting in O(n log n).

Comment: if it is a dupe, vote to close, don't copy,paste answer.

Comment: I'll do both, and I'll edit out the answer from mine and provide a summary instead.

Comment: Thanks, I should have looked it up. Apologize for that.