# How to find the number of pair of points that can form a line with positive slope fast?

Tags: algorithm

Given n pairs of points, how can we get the number of pair of points that can form a line with positive slope fast?

Then there are n lines, where the i-th line contains two integers xi and yi specifying the x and y-coordinates of i-th point. No two points have the same x-coordinate and no two points have the same y-coordinate.

My idea is to sort x first and then compare each point with the other below it.
But it is still O(n^2)

Comment: What are your thoughts? What do you already know?

Comment: If there are n lines, then it takes O(n) time to get lines with positive slopes

Comment: I don't think it is possible in O(n)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort descending by x and then count the number of inversions in y. Both steps are O(n log n).

Explanation: the number of (unordered) pairs with positive slope is the number of pairs {(xi, yi), (xj, yj)} such that xi > xj and yi > yj. When we sort descending by x, we make it so that  xi > xj if and only if i < j. The definition of an inversion in the ys is a pair i < j such that yi > yj.

[Counting the number of inversions quickly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array)

Answer (score 4):

Pick a point (randomly is easiest and has a good expected running time, although you can find a median point deterministically in linear time), split the axes into four quadrants:

```
  x        |
           |   x   x
     x     |  x
-----------x-----------
  x        |
   x       |      x
           | x
```

Denote the quadrants in counter-clockwise direction from top-left by `I`,`II`,`III`,`IV`:

```
II  | I
----|----
III | IV
```

We shall disregard points that lie on the axes (edge case with theoretical probability of 0, and easily dealt with practically).

Note that all points in quadrant `III` form a positively-sloped line with all points in `I`, similarly no points from `II` will form p.s. lines with points in `IV`, so we recursively call:

```
NumPSLines(G) = |I|*|III| +
                NumPSLines(I U II) +
                NumPSLines(II U III) +
                NumPSLines(III U IV)
```

Where `U` denotes union.

Assuming (proof left to reader) that the *expected* values `E(|I|) = ... E(|IV|) = |G|/4 = n/4`  and that the partition into quadrants is linear then we get an expected run time of:

```
T(n) = O(n) + 3T(n/2)
     = O(n) + ... + 3^k * t(n/2^k) // where k = log2(n)
     = O( log2(n) * 3^log2(n) )
     = O(n^(log2(3)) * logn)
     ~ O(n^1.6 * logn)
```

Not sure if that bound is tight; haven't thought about it much.

This solution can be super optimised, although it's a start.

Comment: @Bear, thanks, although the other answer is slightly more efficient and simpler, you should probably choose it!