# Calculating the number of inversions (conceptually?)

Tags: algorithm

all, I'm trying to understand how exactly we are to calculate the number of inversions between two arrays.

Let's say, for example, we have the following two arrays:

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
B = [6, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1]

How would I calculate the number of inversions conceptually?  That is, just looking at these two arrays, disregarding the coding involved.

Also, I know the convention of drawing line segments between the two arrays, but I'm trying to gain a deeper understanding here.

Thank you!

Comment: That question seems more involved in trying to compute the specific number of inversions for a permutation using a sorting algorithm under a specified time.  I'm strictly trying to understand the inversion process intuitively, later to try and solve the problems such as the one you've linked to.

Comment: Inversion of which operators? Generic swaps, side-by-side element swaps, shifts, rotations, ...?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by a number of inversions of two arrays.

**For one array:**
An inversion is a pair (a,b) where a is before b in the order but a > b.
So, conceptually, you can try each pair for B. Let's start with 6, there are 5 inversions: (6,3), (6,5), (6,4), (6,2), (6,1). Next with 3, there are only 2: (3,2), (3,1). And so on, the result here is 13.

However this algorithm is pretty naive and runs O(n^2). Much better solution is based on merge sort algorithm and it runs in O(n log n). You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6424847/1432471). I assume this works only for the first array already sorted.

**For two arrays:** When it comes to 2 arrays (again conceptually), just type your B array above A array and draw lines connecting the same elements. The number of crossings should be the number of inversions. This is exactly how the merge-sort-based algorithm linked above works. Take a look at the picture below:

[image: number of inversions]

The result is still 13, so this method indeed works.