# Algorithm for counting specific type of inversions in an array

Tags: algorithm

I need an algorithm that counts the inversions of type:
Inversion between a and b exists if a has lower index and a > 2b.

Can you think of an algorithm that would do it in O(n logn)?

Comment: This is a clrs question, isnt't it?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done via a small tweak in merge sort algorithm. [Counting inversions in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array)

In the normal standard algorithm during the merge phase you compare elements from left and right half and increase inversions by number of elements remaining in Left portion. Here we increment not by the number of elements remaining in the left half but rather by the number of elements remaining in the left half which are more than twice as large.

Comment: This algorithm looks for standard inversions, my question is about something else: I need a condition a > 2b (not a >= b) to be met.
Thank anyway though

Comment: Just an extra AND condition would do.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a problem with a pointer skipping the inversions.

E.g. merging [3 10] with [2 4] will move the pointer of the right half forward just after comparing it with 3 even though the inversion is formed between 10 and 2. Your suggested algorithm would return 1 inversion while the correct answer is 2.

Comment: well actually, you need to increment it not by the number of elements remaining in left half but rather number of elements in the remaining left half which are more than twice as large.

Answer (score 0):

```
A[1..n]
B[1..n] = copy(A)
sort(B) //n*log(n)

for i = 1 to n-1
  //log(n)
  exists = specialBinarySearch(B, A[i], 1, n)

  //log(n)    
  setHighest(B, A[i], 1, n)
  if exists
    count++

specialBinarySearch(a, key, from, to)
  if from <= to
    mid = from + (to-from)/2

    if a[mid] < floor(key/2)
      return true
    else //must go to left of it to get even smaller value
      specialBinarySearch(a, key, from, mid-1)
  else
    return false

setHighest(a, key, from, to)
  if from <= to
    mid = from + (to-from)/2
    if a[mid] == key
      a[mid] = INT_MAX
    else if a[mid] < key
      setHighest(a, key, mid+1, to)
    else
      setHighest(a, key, from, mid-1)
```

OK. So, basically here are the steps.

1. Copy to an auxiliary array B. This O(n)
2. Sort with any n*log<sup>n</sup> algorithm
3. For each element `a` in A, perform a binary search in B for any element `B[i]` such that `a > 2*B[i]`. O(log<sup>n</sup>). (the algorithm I have written to avoid overflow)
4. Since we do not have to take `B[i]` into account, make it disqualify for comparison by setting `B[i] = infinity`. Another binary search. O(log<sup>n</sup>)
5. Repeat 3 and 4 till it exhausts.

So, lets calculate we have

```
   O(n) + O(n*log(n)) + n*O(log(n))
=> O(n*log(n)) asymptotically
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be solved using dynamic order statistics data structure. I know two alternatives for such a structure:

1. [Order statistic tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)
2. [Indexable skiplist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist)

For each element of the array (`b`) in order, find rank of the value `2b` in the order statistics data structure. Then insert `b` into the order statistics data structure.

Rank of the value `2b` gives number of elements `a`, that have lower index and are less than `2b`. Sum of these numbers gives number of "inversions".