# Minimum number of adjacent swaps

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This is one of the question from online written test.

Books numbered from (1...N) have arrived to a warehouse.

The books are said to be best arranged if a book “i” is present only to the left of book “i+1” (for all i, 1 <= i <= N-1) and that book N is present to the left of book 1. [Yes! Any cyclic sorted sequence is a best arrangement]

Books received are in a random order.Now your task is to find out the minimal number of moves required to achieve the best arrangement described above.

Note that only valid move is to choose a pair of adjacent books and have them switch places.

For Example if the books were initially in the order 3 5 4 2 1

Solution can be

a. First swap the second pair of books: { result : 3 4 5 2 1 }

b. Swap the rightmost pair: { result : 3 4 5 1 2 }

So, in 2 moves we achieve the best arrangement.

I tried but not able to find out solution for this.First I though that i will divide the array in two arrays and then I will apply insertion sort on both the arrays but that is also not working.
Please help me to find out a algo for this question.

Comment: Duplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364607/given-an-array-of-integers-in-random-order-you-have-to-find-the-minimum-number-o

Comment: One of your classmates perhaps?

Comment: Isn't this condition "book “i” is present only to the left of book “i+1” (for all i, 1 <= i <= N-1) " violated in the answer 3,4,5,1,2 given in OP,  as 2 is to right of 3. Or is this condition wrongly stated in OP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [given an array of integers in random order you have to find the minimum number of swaps to convert it to cyclic sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364607/given-an-array-of-integers-in-random-order-you-have-to-find-the-minimum-number-o)

Answer (score 1):

N,1 can be anywhere in the sequence. eg 1..5, could be 3,4,5,1,2. So the first digit could be 1..5, ie 5x as complicated as [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364607/given-an-array-of-integers-in-random-order-you-have-to-find-the-minimum-number-o). So, you'll have to do it 5 times. Use a sort algorithm that has a replaceable compare function.

So for the 3rd test the compare would be:-

```
// returns <0, 0 or >0
int compare(a,b){
     return ((b+N-3)%N) - ((a+N-3)%N);
}
```

Comment: If you want to do it properly then Google "Sorting circular permutations by bounded transpositions", this is a current research problem in Bioinformatics & Computational Biology but the papers are a bit advanced.