# Output the number of pairs that are in the wrong order in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

For example I have the array:

```
int IDs[]={1,21,5,3,12,23,2};
```

The number of pairs that are in the wrong order is `9`. The pairs are: `(21, 5) (21,3) (21, 12) (21,2) (5,3) (5,2) (3,2) (12,2) (23,2)`.

So , my algorithm for this implies two for's:

```
 for(int i=0;i<IDs.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<IDs.length;j++)
        {
            if(IDs[i]>IDs[j]) 
                wrong++;             
        }
    }
```

The problem is that this has a complexity of n<sup>2</sup> and I should have a complexity of maximum n*log n.

Comment: I think you can do this using a modified BST. Everytime you have to branch off to the left (either through adding a new left child or going further down existing nodes), you add new "wrong-order" pairs. Specifically, add a new pair for the node you just went left from, plus a pair for each of that node's descendants to the right. Try it and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The number of pairs in wrong order are called the number of inversions.
With this knowledge, someone can easily find a previous solution:
[Counting inversions in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array)

Comment: thanks a lot . hopefully i found what i need there