# Number of swaps performed by Bubble-Sort on a given array

Tags: arrays, sorting, swap, bubble-sort

I have been given an array and I'm asked to find out the number of Swaps required to sort the array using *Bubble Sort*

Now we know that, we can find the comparisons by `n(n-1)/2` but what I need is the number of `actual swaps`

My first instinct was to use bubble sort and with each swap(), I incremented a Swap variable. But the time complexity of this is a very slow process and I'd like your help to find an optimized way to solve my dilemma

P.S.: I also need to compare whether it is faster to sort it in ascending or descending.... Sorting it twice doubles the time.

**Edit:**

Sorry if I wan't clear enough. I want to find the swaps without using Bubble Sort at all.

Comment: Go with your first instinct. Having an additional constant-time operation (incrementing a count), won't change the asymptotic runtime of the whole sorting method... Why would that be a 'slow process'?

Comment: "_But the time complexity of this is a very slow process_" Wrong. Adding one more operation does nothing to the time complexity in this case. Besides, it's bubble sort. If time complexity was an issue you would NEVER use bubble sort.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication, I don't want to use Bubble Sort at all. I want to know if there is any algorithm to find swaps without using Bubble Sort

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a sequence by swapping adjacent elements using minimum swaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990127/sorting-a-sequence-by-swapping-adjacent-elements-using-minimum-swaps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regard the *applied* `swap()` to `a[i]` and `a[i+1]` as a *bubble-up* of `a[i]`.
Now, asking how many swaps are going to happen is the same as asking how many bubble-up operations are going to happen. Well, and how many do we have of those?

Each `a[i]` will bubble-up for each position `j > i`, where `a[j]<a[i]`. In words `a[i]` will bubble-up for each position to the right, where the elements value at that position is smaller than `a[i]` itself. A pair of elements satisfying this condition is what is known as an [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28discrete_mathematics%29) of `a[]`.

So reformulating your question we could ask: **What is the total number of inversions in `a[]`? (a.k.a. What is the inversion number of `a[]`?)**

This is a well known problem and besides some obvious approaches running in O(n^2) a typical approach to this problem is to tweak merge-sort a bit in order to find this number. And since merge-sort runs in O(n*log(n)) you get the same running time to find the inversion number of `a[]`.

Now that you know that you can tweak merge-sort, I suggest you give it a try on your own on how to do it exactly.

Hint: The main question you have to answer is: When positioning a single element during a merge-step of two arrays, how many inversion did I fix? Then simply add up all of those.

In case you still are stuck after giving it some thought, you can have a look at some full blown solutions here:

- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/
- [Counting inversions in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array)