# Hackerearth bubbleSort

Tags: algorithm, swap, bubble-sort, counting, counting-sort

In Hackerearth i tried solving bubble sort swap counting. and my output always different from correct output.for example;
my output is 2475 and correct output is 2788

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int *A,tm,times=0;
cin >> tm;
A = new int[tm];
for(int i = 0; i<tm;i++) {cin >> A[i];}

int temp;

for(int i = 0; i<tm;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < tm-i-1;j++){
        if(A[j] > A[j+1]){
            times++;;
            temp = A[j];
            A[j] = A[j+1];
            A[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
cout << times;

return 0;
}
```

Am i doing something wrong or correct outputs are wrong?

Comment: Independently of the difference in output you’re getting, since you’re using C++ I would strongly advise using std::vector rather than raw arrays and std::swap versus rolling your own. That reduces the surface area of the code and could potentially eliminate any minor bugs you might have here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Your posting has two problems: (1) it requires input; (2) you haven't provided the test case.  Hard-code the case and finish the posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the swap logic, in place of 
    `A[j]=temp;` 
write 
    `A[j+1]=temp;`

In the outer for loop, `i<tm-1` instead of `i<tm`

Answer (score 0):

May be this is irrelevant, but it is possible to find the number of inversion with a better complexity. This solution will require **O(n^2)**. It can be done in **O(nlogn)** time complexity. The idea is to use **merge** sort and at merging state you already know how many values are greater/smaller from a value without actually counting them. While merging, if a value of right subarray is greater, then all other values right of it are also greater. You just need to count how many values are at right. A detailed and pleasant explanation is provided here.

- [Number of swaps performed by Bubble-Sort on a given array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903666/number-of-swaps-performed-by-bubble-sort-on-a-given-array)
- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/