# Counting number of inversions in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, mergesort, inversion

For the given problem statement we need to calculate the number of inversion in an array so i tried to apply an algorithm using merge sort and calculating the number of inversion while merging and also at time of sorting. While my code gives the same answer for the test cases i fed to the system as my own solutions i am getting a wrong answer on the online judge - Codechef. Please tell me my mistake.

problem link: http://www.codechef.com/COOK43/problems/LPAIR

code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

long long int Merge(int* left,int* right,int* arr,int nl,int nr)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    long long int cnt=0;
    while(i<nl&&j<nr)
    {
        if(left[i]<=right[j])
        {
            arr[k]=left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k]=right[j];
            j++;
            cnt+=nl-i;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i<nl)
    {
        arr[k]=left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<nr)
    {
        arr[k]=right[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    return cnt;
}

long long int MergeSort(int *a,int len)
{
    long long int cnt=0;
    if(len<2)
        return 0;
    int mid=len/2;
    int* left=new int[mid];
    int* right=new int[len-mid];
    for(int i=0;i<mid;i++)
        left[i]=a[i];
    for(int i=mid;i<len;i++)
        right[i-mid]=a[i];
    cnt+=MergeSort(left,mid);
    cnt+=MergeSort(right,len-mid);
    cnt+=Merge(left,right,a,mid,len-mid);
    delete(left);
    delete(right);
    return cnt;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int* fm=new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>fm[i]>>fm[i];
    cout<<MergeSort(fm,n);
}
```

Comment: Formatting nitpicker... spaces, braces and comments are free, use them. ;-)

Comment: thats cheating..you know that..:P

Comment: Just curious, Were you planning on fixing the memory leaks in `MergeSort` before you submit this again?

Comment: @WhozCraig I am just a newbie in programming field and was not able to find the problem in my code so i asked my problem here. But i didn't get whatever you said.

Comment: It means your allocations your making for splitting into the left and right sides before recursing should be deleted *after* the merge is done, otherwise you're leaking memory.

Comment: @WhozCraig i have updated the code and tried to prevent memory leakage by deleting the two temporary arrays. Can you tell me whether it is fine now or not and also what is the problem with my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting inversions in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct approach and you have a very simple problem - the number of inversions for n = 10<sup>5</sup> may overflow integer. Think of how you can fix that.

Comment: i changed the integer cnt to long long int and hence it is able to store the maximum possible inversions that is 10^5C2 = 4999950000
but i am still getting a wrong answer.

Comment: i think yes. the number of n is the number of array elements which are at max 10^5 so an int array can store these much values but int cnt was not able to hold the number of inversions so i made it long long int. but it is still not working.

Comment: i have updated the code. You can tell me now that what is the problem

Comment: I wish I could. The only thing I notice is that you do not print a new line character after the answer. The code seems ligit to me.

Answer (score 0):

**The Error is input pairs of men and women will not given as sorted based on Male Chef Mi.**

Before running merge sort you need to sort the pair  based on Mi < Male number> because male should be standing in an increasing order.

so your array fm should be array of pairs  and then sort this according to Mi.

And then all the operation in merge-sort will be based on second element of fm (fm.second)

[Solution](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/6820888)