# The cmd is taking forever to run a python program

Tags: python, cmd

For some reason, the cmd is taking 2 minutes to run a 18 line python program. I ran it again but it did not do anything.
  Can anyone tell me why it is taking that long?

```
from array import *

file = open("IntegerArray.txt" , "r")

input_array = array('i')

for line in file:
    c = int(line)
    input_array.append(c)

top_array = input_array[:len(input_array)//2]
bottom_array = input_array[len(input_array)//2:]

inversion = 0
max_index = len(top_array) 

for i in range(0, max_index):
    for j in range(i + 1, max_index):
        if top_array[i] > top_array[j]:
            temp = top_array[i]
            top_array[i] = top_array[j]
            top_array[j] = temp
            inversion = inversion + 1
print "inversion = ", inversion
```

Comment: How big is the input?

Comment: about 50,000 numbers

Comment: You can't really judge a program's running time by how many lines it is.  Your code has a doubly-nested loop, so if your input is large, you should expect to take a while.

Comment: I know that it is big but I don't see how it would take that long

Comment: In your case, you are running the code inside the inner loop O(n^2) times.  For n=50,000, this is 2500000000 times.  (actually it is 2500000000/2 times, but still very big)

Comment: You could speed up your inner-loop by using `top_array[i], top_array[j] = top_array[j], top_array[i]` to swap the two values.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array

Comment: It would be _much_ faster if you just used the built-in `sorted()` function to sort `top_array` — i.e. `top_array = array('i', sorted(top_array))` although that won't tally an `inversion` count for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not related to the time, but you can simplify this:

```
        temp = top_array[i]
        top_array[i] = top_array[j]
        top_array[j] = temp
```

to

```
top_array[i], top_array[j] = top_array[j], top_array[i]
```