# How can I count the swaps in a Merge Sort Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, mergesort

I've done the MergeSort algorithm, but I don't know how to count the swaps.

My code is:

```
def mergesortInv(list):
    if len(list) < 2:
        return list
    else:
        middle = len(list) // 2
        left = mergesortInv(list[:middle])   #definim les dues meitats
        right = mergesortInv(list[middle:])
        swaps=???       
    return mergeInv(left, right,swaps)

def mergeInv(left, right,swaps):
    if len(left) < 1:
        return right
    if len(right) < 1:
        return left
    if left[0] <= right[0]:
        return [left[0]] + mergeInv(left[1:],right,swaps)
    else:
        return [right[0]] + mergeInv(left,right[1:],swaps)
```

The output of this algorithm would be the sorted list(the algorithm works in this part) and the  number of swaps: `mergesortInv(list) == ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8], 6)` 6 is the number of swaps.

Comment: swapping happens inside the `else` part of the `mergeInv` method. If you increment an index every time you come there, that should represent total swaps at the end. But you'll probably have to change your suggested function signatures. Either keep a global index (bad) or return the number of swaps in each `mergeInv`call and accumulate them (good).

Comment: Please see [Counting inversions in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array). The answers there show how to count inversions using mergesort, but there are other ways to do this. Please see my answer that compares the speeds of the various algorithms on different list sizes.

Comment: @Anubis I'll try the last option that you've given me

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to use `list` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `list` type. It won't hurt anything here, but it makes it a bit confusing to read your code. And if for some reason you tried to use `list` inside `mergesortInv` to create a list you'd get a mysterious error message.

Comment: I've used `list` because it's a neutral name, but in my original algorithm I have got another name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version of your code that appears to work:

```
def mergesortInv(list, mergeInv):
    if len(list) < 2:
        return list, 0
    else:
        middle = len(list) // 2
        left, lc = mergesortInv(list[:middle], mergeInv)   #definim les dues meitats
        right, rc = mergesortInv(list[middle:], mergeInv)
    merge, mc = mergeInv(left, right)
    return merge, lc + rc + mc

def mergeInvRec(left, right):
    if len(left) < 1:
        return right, 0
    if len(right) < 1:
        return left, 0
    if left[0] <= right[0]:
        res, cnt = mergeInvRec(left[1:], right)
        return [left[0]] + res, cnt
    else:
        res, cnt = mergeInvRec(left, right[1:])
        return [right[0]] + res, len(left) + cnt

def mergeInvFlat(left, right):
    res, cnt = [], 0
    il, ir = 0, 0
    nl, nr = len(left), len(right)
    while il < nl and ir < nr:
        if left[il] <= right[ir]:
            res.append(left[il])
            il += 1
        else:
            res.append(right[ir])
            ir += 1
            cnt += nl - il
    res.extend(left[il:])
    res.extend(right[ir:])
    return res, cnt
```

It's mostly a matter of book keeping. Count the number of swaps at each step and add them. In the very last branch the first element of `right` bubbles all the way past every element of `left` which is why we tally `len(left)` swaps there.

**Edit:** As @PM2Ring points out the recursion in `mergeInv` is a bit reckless and will exceed Python's maximum recursion depth for moderately sized lists.
I've added a non-recursive version. You can switch between the recursive and nonrecursive versions by passing their name as the second arg to the main function.

Comment: Okay, I've caught it now

Comment: @ZRTSTR Note that this code will fail with `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` on lists with around 1000 or more items.

Comment: @PM2Ring Good catch. Will update.

Comment: Much better! And quite a bit faster too. When the list size is over 40 or so it's now faster than most of the other mergesort-based versions in my timeit tests.

Comment: @PM2Ring Just had a look at your linked answer. Impressed. You do seem interested in the topic ;-]

Comment: I get a bit carried away sometimes... :) I quite like doing timeit tests, especially when there are a bunch of fairly different algorithms to compare.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this, but this is just to give you an idea about what I suggested in the comment to your question.

```
def mergesortInv(list):
    if len(list) < 2:
        return list
    else:
        middle = len(list) // 2
        left = mergesortInv(list[:middle])   #definim les dues meitats
        right = mergesortInv(list[middle:])
        # swaps=???
    return mergeInv(left, right)

def mergeInv(left, right):
    """ return a tuple of total swaps and the merged list """
    if len(left) < 1:
        return (0, right)
    if len(right) < 1:
        return (0, left)
    if left[0] <= right[0]:
        swaps, lst = mergeInv(left[1:],right)
        return (swaps, [left[0]] + [lst])
    else:
        swaps, lst = mergeInv(left,right[1:])
        return (swaps + 1, [right[0]] + [lst])
```

Usage,

```
swaps, lst = mergesortInv(mylist)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `mergeInv` returns a tuple, and thus so does `mergesortInv`, but inside `mergesortInv` you have `left = mergesortInv(list[:middle])` and `right = mergesortInv(list[middle:])` so both `left` and `right` get tuples assigned to them. Also, in `mergeInv`, you create nested lists with `[left[0]] + [lst]` and `[right[0]] + [lst]`.

Comment: BTW, a tuple is constructed by the commas, not the parentheses, the parentheses are only needed in some situations to prevent ambiguity. So you can do, eg `return 0, right`.