# How would I get the minimum number of adjacent swaps to equalize two lists that contain the same numbers but in different orders (PYTHON)

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I am wondering how I would get the minimum number of adjacent swaps to equalize two lists that contain the same numbers but in different orders. For example...

```
array_1 = [4,3,2,1]
array_2 = [1,2,3,4]
```

We would want to find the smallest number of adjacent swaps to turn array_1 into array_2.

The answer would be `6` ADJACENT swaps

If anyone can make a function for this in python it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can the values be repeated?

Comment: @GarethMa No, all values are unique

Comment: Great, my answer works then hahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I assumed the numbers are all distinct**

Two steps:

1) Make array_2 sorted

2) Solve for when array_2 is sorted

I'll be using this test case:

```
array_1 = [1, 7, 3, 2, 6]
array_2 = [3, 2, 6, 7, 1]
```

First step:

What we're going to do is do a substitution, such that array_2 is sorted. The most obvious way is to go through each element of array_2 (3, 2, 6, 7, 1). You replace the first one with '1', the second one with '2' and so on.

Example:

```
   array_2 = [3, 2, 6, 7, 1]
-> array_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So you've replaced 3->1, 2->2, 6->3, 7->4, 1->5. Now using the same substitution, update array_1.

```
   array_1 = [1, 7, 3, 2, 6]
-> array_1 = [5, 4, 1, 2, 3]
```

So now it's equivalent to swapping `[5, 4, 1, 2, 3]` to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

2) Solving this

This is well known, and the answer is the number of inversion pairs in the array. For example in [5, 4, 1, 2, 3] there are 4+3=7 inversions, so 7 swapps are required. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array) for example.

I'll provide the first part's code

```
array_1 = [1, 7, 3, 2, 6]
array_2 = [3, 2, 6, 7, 1]
replace_scheme = {} # dictionary
for i in range(len(array_2)): # zero-index still work
    replace_scheme[array_2[i]] = i # array_2[i] -> i
for i in range(len(array_1)):
    array_1[i] = replace_scheme[array_1[i]] # Replaces
print (array_1, inversions(array_1)) # We don't need to update array_2, we know it's sorted
```