# Count pairs (a,b) in two permutations such that index(a) < index(b) in both

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose we are given two permutations of the sequence (1, 2, 3,..N) - for example, for 5 elements, we could have `(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)` and `(3, 2, 4, 1, 5)`.

The task is to find the number of pairs `(a, b)` such that the index of `a` is less than the index of `b` in both of the permutations.

In the above case, there are four such pairs: `(4, 1)` (i.e., `4` comes before `1` in both permutations), `(3, 1)`, `(2, 1)` and `(3, 2)`.

It's clear that this can be solved in O(n<sup>2</sup>), but is it possible to improve on that?

Comment: What are a and b?

Comment: a and b are integers from 1 to n

Comment: so 4 always is larger than 1, isn't it? Without any permutations.

Comment: sorry, my bad, we need to compare indices. I apologize

Comment: Why do you think that this can be done in O(n log n)?

Comment: because it is just comparison based, and in O(n^2) we are iterating through same numbers again and again. Also in the competition in which I found this question gave me TLE if I use O(n^2).

Comment: Can you give more examples?

Comment: Are the indices 0-based or 1-based? I don’t understand the meaning of the 4 resulting pairs you have shown.

Comment: Do you have code for the O(n^2) algorithm?

Comment: the exact number of steps is n(n-1)/2.

Comment: so you comparing numbers from different array? 

can you post value when you comparing, instead of index ?

Comment: *"Also in the competition in which I found this question gave me TLE if I use O(n^2). "* maybe your code was just not efficient enough?

Comment: 3 is left of 2 in both arrays

Comment: @MikeMB nevermind, I misread the problem

Comment: Can you provide a link to the code contest please ?

Comment: @fjardon there is no link, but i got this question in my test for software engineering intern in Uber.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, this can be solved in O(*n* log *n*) time in a quite elegant way. Since the numbers themselves don't really matter (just their indices), relabel them so that the first permutation is trivial; this takes O(*n*) time. The relabelling in the example is `1 → 3`, `2 → 5`, `3 → 1`, `4 → 2`, `5 → 4`.

```
3 4 1 5 2 → 1 2 3 4 5 
1 3 2 5 4 → 3 1 5 4 2
```

Now index(a) < index(b) in the first permutation if and only if a < b, so we just need to count the number of pairs in the second permutation where a < b and index(a) < index(b), i.e. the number of pairs which are in the correct relative order. This is equal to (*n* choose 2) minus the number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)), which can be counted in O(*n* log *n*) time; see e.g. [this other Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/337664/12299000).

Comment: This is a neat trick. But it seems to replace one problem with a different one that doesn't necessarily have a more elegant solution than one we could derive for the original problem, so I'm not sure I agree that this procedure is "quite elegant."

Comment: @גלעדברקן Since inversions are closely related to sorting algorithms, the problem is reduced to a classic one which there are well-known solutions to; the linked Q&A has a solution based on merge sort in about 30 lines of Java. Elegant is a matter of opinion, but I think it's an elegant solution, conceptually simpler and easier to implement than the other answer.

Comment: I agree on that, this solution is easy to implement. For mine you need to have an implemented order statistics tree in your programming language, and if it's not provided, then it's creepy.

Comment: Nice trick! There's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23201616/5801661) in the SO question you posted that can be used almost verbatim to solve this problem. In that answer, the author uses a mapping (they called it rank) from the array values into the first *n* numbers according to their natural ordering. This is your relabelling step, if one [uses the second array instead of `sorted(a)` and add the `(n 2)` part in the `return` line, they have a working code](https://pastebin.com/18zNaax7).

Comment: @MargaretBloom and that same question contains an answer that times the various approaches. "ltree" (and Tim Babych's version of a similar procedure for many of the tests) consistently outperforms the merge sort version. Point being that the answers in the linked question that outperform in the inversion count can be used in a procedure that does not need the remapping in this answer.

Comment: Are you talking about elegance, or performance? Those aren't the same thing; it is almost inevitable that the fastest possible code is not the most elegant. The question is "can this be done in O(n log n) time?", so IMO reducing that to a classic O(n log n) problem in order to answer "yes" is an elegant solution, because it is short and easy to understand if you already know how merge sort works and why it's O(n log n).

Comment: That's fine. I have no problem with us each having a somewhat different concept of elegance.

Answer (score 6):

This can be solved with [order statistics rb tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree).
Let's call the two arrays **a**, and **b**.(they are interchangeable)
Let their length be **n**.
We need the inverse permutation **p** of **b**. (that is: **p[x]** contains the index for the number **x** in **b**)
Let **s** be the set with order statistics.

We will store indices of already visited elements of **b** in **s**.
We iterate from **i**=**0** to **n-1** (let the arrays be zero indexed):
The number of elements after number **a[i]** in **b** is **C = n-1 - p[a[i]]**.
Out of these, we need those elements, which did not appear in **a** yet. This can be calculated using **s**. We know the size of **s**, and in log(n) we can calculate the position of **p[a[i]]** in **s**. Subtract the number of elements that come after **p[a[i]]** in **s** from **C**, and add that to the answer.
At the end of each iteration, we add **p[a[i]]** to **s**.

Edit: If you use c++ with gcc compiler, such a set is already implemented, and [used](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/11080?locale=en) in competitive programming.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it the following way. Lets use the example you gave:

```
3 4 1 5 2 
1 3 2 5 4
```

Keep a structure that (1) we can add a number to, and (2) given a number, can report how many numbers in the structure are greater (e.g., given 2, if the structure contained 1, 3, and 4, it would return 2).

Now iterate from right to left in the first permutation, `A`. For every number, `A[i]`, after the first in the iteration, mark the previously visited number, `A[i+1]`, by inserting in the structure that number's index in the second permutation. Then query the structure for how many elements in it are greater than the index of `A[i]` in `B`.

Back to our example:

```
indexes  0 1 2 3 4
A        3 4 1 5 2 
B        1 3 2 5 4

Iteration right to left on A:
2  skip

5  insert index of 2 in B
   structure: { 2 }
   query structure for how many are
   greater than index of 5 in B
   > 3: 0
   result: 0
   
1  insert 3 in structure
   structure: { 2, 3 }
   query > 0: 2
   result: 2
   
4  insert 0 in structure
   structure: { 0, 2, 3}
   query > 4: 0
   result: 2
   
3  insert 4 in structure
   structure: { 0, 2, 3, 4 }
   query > 1: 3
   result: 2 + 3 = 5
```