# Counting inversions in an array with typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, algorithm, mergesort

I've been banging my head against this error for a couple of hours now and can't seem to find where the error is.

I'm trying to count the inversions in a given array and all my tests pass except when using this array as input [6, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3].

The logic is as follows; given array A[1... n], for every i < j, find all inversion pairs such that A[i] > A[j]

The number I receive for this array is 14 inversions and the correct answer is 8.

The code so far is this

```
function mergeCount(left: number[], right: number[]): number {
  let count = 0;
  let leftCounter = 0;
  let rightCounter = 0;

  while (leftCounter < left.length && rightCounter < right.length) {
    if (left[leftCounter] < right[rightCounter]) {
      leftCounter += 1;
    } else {
      count += left.length - leftCounter;
      rightCounter += 1;
    }
  }

  return count;
}

function countInversions(input: number[]): number {
  if (input.length < 2) return 0;

  const middle = Math.floor(input.length / 2);

  const left = input.slice(0, middle);
  const right = input.slice(middle);

  return countInversions(left) + countInversions(right) + mergeCount(left, right);
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing or what's wrong with my code?

EDIT:

So the problem was that I wasn't sorting the arrays when splitting them up, I was just updating the counter. The working solution that I came up with is the following

```
function mergeCount(left: number[], right: number[]): { output: number[]; count: number } {
  let count = 0;
  let leftCounter = 0;
  let rightCounter = 0;
  const output: number[] = [];

  while (leftCounter < left.length && rightCounter < right.length) {
    if (left[leftCounter] < right[rightCounter]) {
      output.push(left[leftCounter]);
      leftCounter += 1;
    } else {
      output.push(right[rightCounter]);
      count += left.length - leftCounter;
      rightCounter += 1;
    }
  }

  return {
    output: output.concat(left.slice(leftCounter)).concat(right.slice(rightCounter)),
    count,
  };
}

function countInversions(input: number[]): { output: number[]; count: number } {
  if (input.length < 2) return { output: input, count: 0 };

  const middle = Math.floor(input.length / 2);

  const { output: left, count: a } = countInversions(input.slice(0, middle));
  const { output: right, count: b } = countInversions(input.slice(middle));
  const { output, count: c } = mergeCount(left, right);

  return { output, count: a + b + c };
}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm trying to implement an algorithm that counts inversions in a given array, using merge sort in this case. basically this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15151050/12536796 (written in python)

Comment: Do you mean count the number pairs where the first number is larger than the second?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Just edited it and included the logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python code you linked to also sorts the array - you do not. This can cause wrong answers, because the mergesort-based inversion counting algorithm requires that you also sort the array while you're at it (otherwise, the shortcut it uses won't be valid).

Simply merge `left` and `right` in your `mergeCount` function, return that too and it should work.

The highlighted Python below is what's missing in your code:

```
 while i < left_len and j < len(right):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            result.append(left[i]) # this
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j]) # and this
            count += left_len - i
            j += 1
```

---

To give more background on the mergesort inversion-counting idea:

In mergesort, we have two sorted halves `H1` and `H2`: `H1` is sorted, `H2` is sorted. We have a merge function that merges these two, efficiently, into one big sorted array.

Now, that is (well, should be) done in the OP's while loop. Note that, if, using his notation:

```
left[leftCounter] > right[rightCounter]
```

(his else condition), then because `left` is sorted, all the elements after `leftCounter` will also be larger than `right[rightCounter]`, so we have `left.length - leftCounter` inversions -  allowing us to count more than 1 at once.

Of course, this only holds if you let mergesort do its thing and actually sort the array.

Comment: You are right, sorting the array was the problem, thanks! Edited the question with the solution I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation looks quite complicated. I think it could be a lot simpler (and accurate).

Iterate over all elements in an outer loop. Let's call the index `i`. Inside the inner loop, iterate over all elements greater than `i` and compare them against the outer index element.

```
function countInversions(input: number[]): number {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        for (const num of input.slice(i + 1)) {
            if (input[i] > num) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: This is also much much slower.

Comment: I thought of this but I'm pretty sure this solution has a time complexity of O(n2) and there are ways of make it O(n log n)

Comment: @IVlad In my experience, having code that is readable and accurate is much more important (and useful) in real-world situations than complicated code that's inaccurate. If you have another idea feel free to post it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance the code is a mergesort, not Carmack's inverse square root. It's easy enough to fix.