# An Divide and conquer algorithm with complexity O(n log n)

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I have two sequences of numbers (a1, a2, ... , an) and (b1, b2, ... , bn). For any
i, j ∈ [n] we say (ai, bi) and (aj, bj ) agree if either ai < aj ∧ bi < bj or ai > aj ∧ bi > bj
I can assume that all numbers are different.) Otherwise they disagree. Let A be the number of pairs that agree, and D be the number of pairs that disagree. Give an algorithm to compute A − D in time O(n log n).

I have no ideas how to solve it by divide and conquer algorithms. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be reduced to the problem of counting the number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) in a sequence.

First, rewrite the input as if it is a single array of pairs (a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>), (a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>), ... (a<sub>n</sub>, b<sub>n</sub>), and then sort this sequence in ascending order of the a<sub>i</sub> components. Since the numbers are all different, in the resulting sequence we have a<sub>i</sub> < a<sub>j</sub> if and only if i < j. It follows that the number D is equal to the number of inversions in the resulting sequence of b<sub>i</sub> components, i.e. the number of pairs (i, j) where i < j and b<sub>i</sub> < b<sub>j</sub>. The number A is equal to n(n - 1)/2 - D, since every pair either "agrees" or "disagrees".

The inversions in that sequence can be counted in O(n log n) time using a divide-and-conquer algorithm based on merge sort, as detailed in [this other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array).