# Efficiently counting matching inversions between multiple lists at once

Tags: algorithm, ranking

This is a question about taking multiple rankings of the same elements and computing a statistic that depends on whether each possible inversion matches between one or more lists or not.

Given

- *L* equal-length lists of length *N* comprising the first *N* integers in various orders
- an arbitrary set of *L* weights [image: weights], one corresponding to each list
- some arbitrary non-linear scalar function *f*

I'd like to compute in *O(L N* log *N)* time (it's trivial to do in *O(L N^2)* time) the following quantity:

[image: objective]

where

[image: indicator] represents whether the integer *i* appears before the integer *j* in list *l* .

Is there a known algorithm for doing this? Or is it known to be impossible in *O(L N* log *N)* time?

So far I've found a [binary-indexed trees inversion counting algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23201616/5836951) and I'm wondering if I could get what I need by building upon this idea.