# How to calculate the similarity of two movies ranking list effciently?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

> Problem description:
>
> You and Peter are talking about `n` movies, which are represented by integers `[1,n]`. You have made a ranking list for the movies according to your preference. Now, Peter tells you his ranking list. You want to know how similar your and Peter's tastes are. For 2 movies `i, j`, if you and Peter both rank movie `i` before movie `j`, You will get11 similarity. Please output the total similarity.

I know that I can solve this problem in brute force way. Its Java code is like this:

```java
int n = in.nextInt();
int[] rankingListOfMe = new int[n];
int[] rankingListOfPeter = new int[n];
int[] peterMovie2RankingIndex = new int[n + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) rankingListOfMe[i] = in.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    rankingListOfPeter[i] = in.nextInt();
    peterMovie2RankingIndex[rankingListOfPeter[i]] = i;
}
long similarity = 0L;
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    if (rankingListOfMe[i] == rankingListOfPeter[0]) continue;
    int curJMovieIndex = peterMovie2RankingIndex[rankingListOfMe[i]];
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        if (peterMovie2RankingIndex[rankingListOfMe[j]] < curJMovieIndex) similarity++;
    }
}
```

Array `rankingListOfXX` is the array whose index is the movie ranking and it stores movie id.  Array `peterMovie2RankingIndex` is the array, with length n+1, whose index is the movie id and it stores corresponding movie ranking, to get the movie's ranking by the movie id easily. every time I traverse an movie id, I just count how many movies satisfy the request. Although this way can solve the problem, I wonder if there is any other way to solve if more efficiently. The time complexity of algorithm above is `O(n^2)`, which is too much for me. I've been thinking for a while but don't know where to optimize. I think it has something with sort algorithm but I don't know how to use sort algorithm to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void similarity(int[] me, int[] peter){
    int[] peterTemp = new int[peter.length];
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < me.length; i++){
        map.put(me[i], i);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < peter.length; i++){ 
        peterTemp[peterTemp.length - (i + 1)] = map.get(peter[i]);
    }

    // as David Eisenstat pointed out we are going to count inversion in array, invCount method copied from here
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array
    System.out.println(invCount(peterTemp));
}

long merge(int[] arr, int[] left, int[] right) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
    while (i < left.length || j < right.length) {
        if (i == left.length) {
            arr[i+j] = right[j];
            j++;
        } else if (j == right.length) {
            arr[i+j] = left[i];
            i++;
        } else if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
            arr[i+j] = left[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[i+j] = right[j];
            count += left.length-i;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

long invCount(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length < 2)
        return 0;

    int m = (arr.length + 1) / 2;
    int left[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, m);
    int right[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, m, arr.length);

    return invCount(left) + invCount(right) + merge(arr, left, right);
}
```

test:

```
for {1, 5, 6, 7} and  {6, 7, 1, 5} result is 2
for {4, 7, 8, 3, 1, 2} and {3, 8, 7, 1, 2, 4} result is 7
```

Explanation:‌ If we build `peterTemp` like the following:

```
peterTemp[i] = map.get(peter[i]);
```

for every `i, j` such that `i > j` and `peterTemp[i] >‌ peterTemp[j]`
we found a similarity. I built `peterTemp` like this `peterTemp[peterTemp.length - (i + 1)] = map.get(peter[i]);` to use the referenced code only.

Comment: Either add an explanation or add some relevant comments