Finding the most optimal way for updating a dynamic-programming array
Imagine there are n people in a line, which every one of them has there unique value for themselves from 1 to n, we try to sort them like this:
repeat
    swapped = false
    for i from 1 to n do:
        if a[i] > a[i+1] then
            add a friendship between a[i] and a[i+1]
            swap(a[i], a[i+1])
            swapped = true
        end if
    end for
until not swapped

As you see, with each swap there goes a friendship between them, and for a person, if they didn't get swapped with another person, there won't be any friendship between them, the question is after the operation is done for an input, what the maximum number of people who are not friends ?!
Example input:
3
3 1 2

Example output:
2

I tried to solve this problem using this code:
n = int(input())
permutation = list(map(int, input().split()))
dp = [[] for _ in range(n)]
max_length = 0
for i in range(n):
    dp[i].append(i)
    for j in range(i):
        if permutation[j] < permutation[i]:
            addable = True
            for k in dp[j]:
                if (permutation[k] > permutation[i] and k < i) or (permutation[k] < permutation[i] and k > i):
                    addable = False
                    break
            if addable and len(dp[j]) + 1 > len(dp[i]):
                dp[i] = dp[j].copy()
                dp[i].append(i)
    if len(dp[i]) > max_length:
        max_length = len(dp[i])

print(max_length)

which works great for all the inputs and gives us the right answer as I checked, but it has a time complexity of O(n^3) which totally not great for large inputs.
Is there a way to optimize this code ?! Or at least there is another solution and approach to this ?!
This code assumes that with each swap, an edge from a complete graph with n vertices gets removed and with this have in mind, there will be edges between two indexes of permutation if and only if the index that is higher than the other has higher value.

What does "maximum number of people who are not friends" mean, exactly?

You seem to be counting the number of inversions (that is, pairs (x, y) such that x < y and a[x] > a[y]). If that's the case, it's done in O(n*log(n)): you sort the array with your favorite algorithm while counting the number of inversions you're undoing on each step. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array .

Why is the answer 2 for the sample input? There is only 1 pair of people that are not friends after the sorting.

Your question would be more clear if you stated it in words at the beginning, without reference to code (including, for example, an explanation of how it is determined if two persons are friends), then give your example(s) for illustration, then (and only then) present the code you have tried and explain why it is lacking.

@nocomment
So to make it clear, Two people are friends after the operation is done, if and only if they are swapped in the process of sorting, with that said when we try to sort them with the given algorithm, some friendships between some people (which  to be clear, you can consider each of them has a name and their name is their index from the beginning) will happen.
For the given example when the algorithm executes 3 and 1 will be swapped, so they will become friends, afterwards the queue will look like this:
1 3 2
after 3 and 2, the queue is sorted and 1 2 are not friends

So the problem is actually solved if we try to find the Longest Increasing Subsequent (LIS), with that said, we don't even need to execute the algorithm at all. The code for answering the question would be something like this:
n = int(input())
permutation = list(map(int, input().split()))
dp = []
for i in range(n):
    low, high = 0, len(dp)
    while low < high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if dp[mid] < permutation[i]:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid
    if low == len(dp):
        dp.append(permutation[i])
    else:
        dp[low] = permutation[i]

print(len(dp))

To describe this code in short, it iterates on the elements and makes an array with the respect to the order of the elements in the original array, that is increasing, and it will become the longest one because we consider each element and modify the dp array (which will be the array of Longest increasing subsequent) respectively. The length of dp array will be our answer.
